# gradle-release-plugin no tags but generate version on CI

Tags: git, maven, jenkins, gradle-release-plugin

We have a gradle release plugin being used in our project, today if you run gradle release it does what i've listed below.

- Builds the code and creates war with specific version
- Does release plugin specifics (vcs update check(s), tags the release, ups the version automatically and publishes to vcs)
- also we have a custom step `updateVersion.dependsOn createDbMigrationFile`

I would like to build on CI (jenkins) and tell it NOT TO TAG in git but perform the rest of the steps, reason being is our DevOps requires us to up the version with EACH build (this i cannot change) however i don't think this is tag worthy. (#2)I'd like a separate build job to perform Just the tag, the custom step and eventually release notes from the last TAG build.

Bonus points for number two however I'm just after the "build without a TAG generated" portion right now.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to have that support in the plugin because gradle already offers that feature.

Create a jenkins job and let it run for example

```
gradle release -x createReleaseTag -x updateVersion -x commitNewVersion
```

And it will skip the given -x tasks

Comment: Thanks! I ultimately did this, but it was at my last job. :-)